# Physically based rendering - Pink material iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

I am using SceneKit to show a 3D model on iOS. I would like to use PBR. At the moment I am using the scene editor not coding to edit my materials. I can set any field to PNGs at the models material (metalness, normals, etc..) except the roughness. When I set it, the whole model turns pink. If I use float value, there is no problem. Do you have any idea, what the problem could be?

Comment: the problem seems in the roughness map you're using